# Delete the repeating items from first list

Tags: javascript, typescript, list

I have two list:-
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6],
b=[2,3,6]

I want to compare both list and delete the repeating items from list a
Like in this case new list a will be=[1,4,5]
Note:i want to view the items of list a which are not present in list b

Comment: Please read the question again@CodeReady

Comment: You could use above answer and simply achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let b = [2,3,6];


function symmetricDifference(setA, setB) {
    var _difference = new Set(setA);
    for (var elem of setB) {
        if (_difference.has(elem)) {
            _difference.delete(elem);
        } else {
            _difference.add(elem);
        }
    }
    return _difference;
}

let result = symmetricDifference(new Set(a), new Set(b));

console.log( [...result])
```

Answer (score 0):

`var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
 var arr2 = [2,3,6];
 var arr3 = arr1.filter(value => !arr2.includes(value));
 console.log(arr3);`

if you want to delete the values from arr1 then use splice function or again filter function